# MySQL - update row with difference in column between current and a previous row

Tags: mysql

I have a table data_temp with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `data_temp` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `deviceid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `registeraddress` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value` decimal(20,9) NOT NULL,
  `time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `value_diff` decimal(20,9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000000000',
  `time_diff` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
)
```

id is unique but not contiguous.
Records are unique for deviceid/registeraddress/time.
Records are inserted which contain values for id,deviceid,registeraddress,value and time.
I want to calculate value_diff and time_diff which are the difference in value between the inserted record and the previous record corresponding to deviceid and registeraddress and difference in time in seconds.

The table already has a lot of records all without the value_diff and time_diff calculated so I want to update the existing data in the table with these values.

Here is some sample data:

```
id,  deviceid, registeraddress, value,time    
11102116190949258, 101, 856, 34.000000000, 2011-10-21 16:19:00
11102116240432553, 101, 856, 38.000000000, 2011-10-21 16:24:00
11102116290249672, 101, 856, 44.000000000, 2011-10-21 16:29:00
11102116340121243, 101, 856, 54.000000000, 2011-10-21 16:34:00
11102116390025291, 101, 856, 57.000000000, 2011-10-21 16:39:00
11102116440032519, 101, 856, 63.000000000, 2011-10-21 16:44:00
```

I can do the following select on the table which will list the data that I want:

```
SELECT 
    r_B.deviceid, 
    r_B.registeraddress,
    r_B.value,
    r_B.time, 
    COALESCE(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(r_B.time,r_A.time)), 0) AS time_diff,
    COALESCE(r_B.value-r_A.value, 0) AS value_diff
FROM data_temp r_B
    LEFT OUTER JOIN data_temp r_A
    ON r_B.deviceid = r_A.deviceid 
        AND r_B.registeraddress = r_A.registeraddress 
        AND r_B.time > r_A.time
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT r_C.time 
        FROM data_temp r_C
        WHERE r_C.deviceid = r_C.deviceid 
            AND r_C.registeraddress = r_C.registeraddress 
            AND r_C.time > r_A.time 
            AND r_C.time < r_B.time
    )
ORDER BY r_B.deviceid, r_B.registeraddress, r_B.time
```

result:

```
id,  deviceid, registeraddress, value, time, value_diff, time_diff
11102116190949258, 101, 856, 34.000000000, 2011-10-21 16:19:00, 0,   0.000000000
11102116240432553, 101, 856, 38.000000000, 2011-10-21 16:24:00, 300, 4.000000000
11102116290249672, 101, 856, 44.000000000, 2011-10-21 16:29:00, 300, 6.000000000
11102116340121243, 101, 856, 54.000000000, 2011-10-21 16:34:00, 300, 10.000000000
11102116390025291, 101, 856, 57.000000000, 2011-10-21 16:39:00, 300, 3.000000000
11102116440032519, 101, 856, 63.000000000, 2011-10-21 16:44:00, 300, 6.000000000
```

I have been trying for a couple of days now to work out how to write the corresponding update. I have tried the following:

```
UPDATE data_temp r_B
    LEFT OUTER JOIN data_temp r_A
    ON r_B.deviceid = r_A.deviceid 
        AND r_B.registeraddress=r_A.registeraddress 
        AND r_B.time > r_A.time
SET r_B.time_diff = COALESCE(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(r_B.time,r_A.time)), 0),
    r_B.value_diff = COALESCE(r_B.value-r_A.value, 0)
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT r_C.time 
        FROM data_temp r_C 
        WHERE r_C.deviceid = r_B.deviceid 
            AND r_C.registeraddress = r_B.registeraddress 
            AND r_C.time > r_A.time 
            AND r_C.time < r_B.time
    )
```

But of course get the slightly frustrating MySQL error:

```
Error Code: 1093
You can't specify target table 'r_B' for update in FROM clause
```

The problem here is with the WHERE clause at the end. The update works without the clause but gives the wrong result (all records are updated with the difference between the current and the oldest record not the previous record). Everything else in the statement works except the WHERE clause.

I have been researching this for quite a while now and haven't found a good solution so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could select the old data into a temporary table and then do an update joining with that table.

Comment: Thanks Michael - the problem is not in the join it's in the WHERE clause. I've updated thee question to reflect this. cheers.

Comment: Sure, I understand. But if you construct a new table with the appropriate data, you can join to that static table without the `WHERE` clause, and you won't run into the same error.

Comment: OK - must admit I can't see how that would work. How do you construct a new table and refer to it all within the update statement and not use the WHERE clause? My SQL is probably a bit limited so would love to know how this could be done.

Comment: You would need two separate statements. First `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE  new_data SELECT…` where the `SELECT` generates a result set with the `deviceid` and the columns you wish to update. Then `UPDATE data_temp dt JOIN new_data nd USING(deviceid,registeraddress) SET td.time_diff=nd.time_diff, td.value_diff=nd.value_diff`.